# Routing issues MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I am in the process of learning MVC, and currently looking at routing.

I have the following issue: Here is my RegisterRoutes method:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute("Customer", "{controller}/{action}/{objCustomer}",
            new {controller = "Customer", action = "CreateCustomer", id = UrlParameter.Optional});
}
```

If I ran my application, should **hxxp://localhost:12454/** not display the View called by CreateCustomer action in the CustomerController, in other words, the URL should like this? **hxxp://localhost:12454/Customer/CreateCustomer**

**NOTE:** I replaced http with hxxp, to not try and create a link

What am I not understanding correctly here?

Here is my whole Global.asax.cs class.

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute("Customer", "{controller}/{action}",
              new { controller = "Customer", action = "CreateCustomer", UrlParameter.Optional});
    }
}
```

And here is my CustomerController:

```
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    // GET: Customer
    public ActionResult ShowCustomer(Customer objCustomer)
    {
        return View(objCustomer);
    }

    public ActionResult CreateCustomer()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: just check that in your routes there is extra `, UrlParameter.Optional `

Comment: make sure that this route is above all the other routes

Comment: What do you mean this route should be above all other routes? I only have this one route defined.

Comment: I have a model Named Customer as well, within the Model folder. Will this cause any problems?

Comment: i don't think so..just try it..and i mean to say that remove this route from global.asax file and paste it on top above default route in routeconfig.cs file in appstart folder.

Comment: Thanks. Removing the MapRoute from Global.asax.cs and pasting it above the route in RouteConfig, worked.  Should I know place all my routes in RouteConfig?

Comment: You have to place all your routes in routeconfig file and you have to just register them in global.asax file.

Comment: If you want to place this in an Answer, I will accept your Answer as the solution, or you can modify your existing answer, and I will accept it.  Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `'id'` you are using `objCustomer` in your routes then you have to specify `objCustomer` as optional route parameter.

Modify routes as shown below :

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

  routes.MapRoute("Customer", "{controller}/{action}/{objCustomer}",
        new {controller = "Customer", action = "CreateCustomer", objCustomer = UrlParameter.Optional});
}
```

**Make all the custom routes inside routeconfig.cs file inside AppStart folder and don't forget to put this custom route above the default route.**

Comment: @akemp..make sure that you have a Customer controller inside controller folder with createcustomer action and for testing put a breakpoint on createcustomer action and see if its coming there or not

Comment: My CreateCustomer nethod does not except any parameters, I think this was the issue. But how do I change the MapRoute() to accomodate no parameter in the default url? For instance, I have the following now, but does not work:
routes.MapRoute("Customer", "{controller}/{action}",
                  new { controller = "Customer", action = "CreateCustomer" });

Comment: @akemp..the route you showed should work..see there must be problem somewhere else and as shown in my answer `objCustomer` is optional you can give some value to `objCustomer` or not it will not create any problem.

Comment: I do not see anything that can go wrong. I am gonna update my question now, and post my whole Global.asax.cs, and then you would be able to see

Comment: @akemp..also post controller action